# Struts2 debug=browser does not capture url parameters in action class variables?

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2, ognl, xwork

I have a very simple action class with one member variable "data". when I submit the normal url it shows value in tomcat console like:`Test action data=hello`

```
public class ActionTest extends ActionSupport {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2606731098320589210L;
private String data;

public String getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}

@Action(value = "mytestaction")
public String execute() {
    System.out.println("Test action data="+data);
    return SUCCESS;
}
}
```

If I use debug mode like modifying url with **mytestaction.action?data=hello&debug=browser**
in tomcat console it shows `Test action data=null`. But it shows the value in browser ognl context tree in parameters. However the same `data` is null when Action class is expanded.

In other debug mode like **debug=xml** it comes as

```
<actionErrors /> 
<actionMessages /> 
<class>class com.ycs.fe.actions.ActionTest</class> 
<data>hello</data> 
<errorMessages /> 
<errors /> 
<fieldErrors />
```

and in **debug=console** mode if i print the OGNL `#action.data =>shows hello`
also `#parameters.data[0] => shows hello`.

Is this a genuine bug? or am i missing something? I tried with convention as well as mapping in struts.xml, but both have same result.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the above action class.  What version of s2 are you using? What do you get from `<s:property value="data"/>` in the jsp.

Comment: `<s:property value="data"/>` does not matter in action class its coming as null, I am using struts 2.2.1.